# Delphi 2010 and Firebird - what DLL need to be included to deploy

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

Assuming the Firebird client is installed what additional files need to be included with a Delphi 2010 application that uses dbExpress to access the Firebird database.

I assume dbxfb.dll (midas is included in the project 'uses') is required. Any others?

Answer (score 3):

@John, you need deploy these files

- dbxfb.dll  (firebird dbexpress driver)
- dbxconnections.ini
- dbxdrivers.ini
- midas.dll (if you use midas, unless you use the midaslib unit)
- fbclient.dll (the Firebird client library)

Additionally you can check theses links

- [Deploying dbExpress Database Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications)
- [Deploying Database Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Deploying_Database_Applications)
- [Minimum Firebird Client Installation on Windows](http://www.destructor.de/firebird/minimumclient.htm)

Comment: looks like you don't need these dbxconnections.ini
dbxdrivers.ini